# Spaces (Mission Control) jumps to a space but won't stay there

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

I have two spaces. When I try to jump from the left space to the right one using the swipe gesture, the right space shows briefly but then the screen immediately jumps back to the left.

As a result, I can't get to my right space. As you can imagine, this is quite annoying. I just noticed this happening in the last couple of days.

In my left space I'm running Sublime Text 3. I also have a few Google Chrome windows. In my right space I have more Chrome windows.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.3. I have none of the checkboxes checked in the Mission Control section under System Preferences.

There are a few "workarounds":

1. If I move **all** of my Chrome windows to the right space, I don't have the problem anymore. This hardly solves the problem.
2. As a last resort, I can kill the right space, which at least gives me access to those windows. This does not address my core problem (which comes back shortly).

Any ideas on the culprit? What can I do to fix, other than a workaround (such as the ones I list above)?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem at present, so it is "solved". So, "hooray" (spoken in a quiet, self-defeated voice).